# How Binary Numbers Represented as Characters

Tags: linux, windows, linux-kernel, character-encoding, operating-system

As you know, when we are talking about character sequences we have some encoding like ASCII and Unicode and ... I want to know how the operating system can understand 65 should be represented as an 'A' character. In other words, how OS can turn this binary or hexadecimal number representation to a graphical (character) representation? How did this happen in OSes like Windows or Linux? Unfortunately, I didn't find out any information about this underlying concept of OSes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is up to the font. The simplest fonts are simply a numbered list of tiny pictures like <kbd>A</kbd>.

Here's an example of a [bitmap font in Linux](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/lib/fonts/font_8x8.c#L664):

```
    /* 65 0x41 'A' */
    0x38, /* 00111000 */
    0x6c, /* 01101100 */
    0xc6, /* 11000110 */
    0xfe, /* 11111110 */
    0xc6, /* 11000110 */
    0xc6, /* 11000110 */
    0xc6, /* 11000110 */
    0x00, /* 00000000 */
```

The number 65 is simply mapped to 8 other numbers, here expressed in hexadecimal. The comments helpfully show them in binary, and if you squint, you can make out an "A" drawn out by the 1s.

When the system wants to show character number 65, it looks at this table, and then draws each `0`-bit black and each `1`-bit white (or vice versa for black-on-white text). This makes the "A" show up.

What stops you from changing the picture to make 65 show up as a completely different character? Nothing! People routinely did this, like how the Swedes changed letter number 123 from showing `{` to showing `ä` so that they could write their language.

Modern fonts are much more advanced and contain strokes, lines and curves, instead of tiny pictures like this, but the same concepts apply.

Answer (score 0):

The programmer has to specify that the value at location X is a character, integer, executable instruction, etc. It does not happen automatically.The operating system code needs to keep track of what type of data it stored in every location.

> In other words, how OS can turn this binary or hexadecimal number representation to a graphical (character) representation?

To convert a number to a string, you have to write or use library code to do it.

```
 String Convert to Hex (BYTE VALUE)

 string digits [16] = '0', '1', '2', '3', ..., 'A', 'B', 'C', ... 'F' ;

 Result = digits [value >> 4] + digits [value AND FF#16] 

 Return Result
```